# What's the diff between 'cat' and 'echo' command with awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

This is test.file:

```
2017
2018
```

This is what I tried in the terminal:

```
$ echo 2 | awk '{ print 6 }'   
6
$ cat test.file | awk '{ print 6 }'
6
6
```

**My question is:**

Why doesn't `echo` show number '6' two times like `cat` does?

Comment: BTW, `awk '{print 6}' <test.file` is more efficient, as it lets `awk` read straight from the input file, as opposed to starting up a separate `/bin/cat` program and requiring `awk` to read from a FIFO attached to that program's output. It's a relatively small difference here, but can be a much larger one in scenarios where a program (like `wc -c` or `sort`) can optimize its behavior when given a real, seekable descriptor rather than a FIFO.

Comment: (For example, `wc -c` can just ask the OS how large the attached file is, or `sort` can have a different thread skip ahead to start sorting the second half of the file while another thread is working on the first half -- but only with a real file, not with a pipeline).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Would `awk '{ print 6 }' < file` be more efficient than just plain old `awk '{ print 6 }' file`?

Comment: @Mr.Llama, those are effectively equivalent; I show the `<` approach because it's more general to the wider set of cases where `cat file |` is used, but `awk '{print 6}' file` is entirely valid, and there are certainly situations where it's preferable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file you're feeding with `cat` contains two lines of input, whereas what you stream with `echo` is only one line.

If you change the `echo`s to be equivalent, as in:

```
{ echo 2017; echo 2018; } | awk '{ print 6 }'
```

...you get the same two lines of output.

---

The thing to remember here is that an `awk` script is composed of chunks of the general form `PATTERN { BLOCK }`, where the PATTERN determines whether and when the BLOCK is executed. (Both of these are optional: The default pattern is to run for every line; the default block is `{ print $0 }`, to print the current line in full).

When you just have `{ print 6 }`, you're keeping the default pattern (which is to run that block for every line of input). Hence, when you feed in two lines of input, `{ print 6 }` is run twice.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer again.

Comment: @xoyabc, glad it helped. If you consider the question closed, please consider clicking the checkbox next to the answer to mark the question answered.